# <h:CommandButton> action attribute not working in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 for my application.

In the below code, the action attribute of the `Account Details`button is not working, i.e. the method is not getting invoked and nothing happens when I click the button.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel id="lblCustomerDetails" value="Details of CustomerId: "></h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputText id="txtCustomerId" value="#{customerInfo.customerId }"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputLabel id="lblCustomerName" value="Customer name: "></h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputText id="txtCustomerName" value="#{customerInfo.customerNAme }"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputLabel id="lblAccounts" value="Accounts: "></h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="drpdownAccounts">
        <f:selectItems value="#{customerInfo.accounts }"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>      
    <h:outputLabel id="lblEmail" value="Email: "></h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputText id="txtEmail" value="#{customerInfo.email }"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputLabel id="lblAccountDetails" value="Select an account no. for details"></h:outputLabel>
    <h:commandButton id="btnAcountDetails" value="Account Details" action="#{accountBean.accountDetails }"></h:commandButton>
    <h:messages></h:messages>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Below is the `AccountBean`:

```
public class AccountBean {

private int accountNo;
private String customerName;
private double accountBalance;
private String accountType;

    //Getters and setters

public String accountDetails(){
   //Some logic and return
       return "success"; 

}
}
```

This is the managed bean present in the faces-config fie:

```
<managed-bean>     
    <managed-bean-name>customerInfo</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.bean.CustomerInfo</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>        
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>     
    <managed-bean-name>accountBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.bean.AccountBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>        
</managed-bean>
```

There might be somethng silly I am missing in the code but not able to figure it out, wasted a lot of time with this and hence thought of posting. Pointers are appretiated.

Comment: Please exclude the causes listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 First suspect: where's the `<h:form>`? How would you submit a form without a form? This is however shown in chapter 1 of every sane JSF tutorial, so it would be a bit *too* obvious mistake indicating a lack of understanding of basic HTML (which you'd preferably learn first before diving into JSF as JSF is ultimately basically "just" a HTML code generator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the whole markup you have, but could it just be a missing `<form>` tag somewhere in your page? AFAIK in MyFaces Trinidad, form controls and buttons don't do anything unless they are inside a `<tr:form>` tag.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I didn't see BalusC's comment before answering this... the answer from his link looks like it has everything including the kitchen sink, so yeah go there!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If pasting your code inside

```
<h:form>
```

and still you are not able to solve your problem then try to use

```
<a4j:JsFunction>
```

It will solve your problem for JSF 1.2

```
<h:form>
<h:commandbutton onclick = "clickme()" />
<a4j:JsFunction name = "clickme" action = "#{yourBean.YourMethod}"  /> 
</h:form>
```